# How to delay Eureka client registration with Eureka Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a `Spring Boot` application which is also a `Eureka client`. The normal behavior of the application is to register with `Eureka server` on start up as `UP`. I have a requirement that the application shouldn't register with the Eureka server until smoke testing is completed during deployment.

Is there a way to delay the registration with Eureka Server or register as `OUT_OF_SERVICE` with some type of configuration changes? I am aware of the [Eureka REST endpoints](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) to register, unregister, and change status.

Comment: How does your application know when smoke testing is finished?

Comment: A `Rundeck` job will call a couple of endpoints of the aforementioned service after the deployment, probably a health endpoint. Once it gets an HTTP response code 200 back from the service, it will call the Eureka status change endpoint to update the status of the affected service to `UP`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `eureka.instance.initial-status=OUT_OF_SERVICE` will register the service with that status.

Comment: Didn't work in Dalston release. It's still showed up as `UP`.

Comment: @spencergibb Please expound on your answer to include what causes a service to transition from OUT_OF_SERVICE to UP.

Comment: Hi Faron, might be a little late here but you can do the transition from OUT_OF_SERVICE to UP using the eurekas rest endpoint call.

The Rest Endpoint is : 
PUT    /eureka/v2/apps/appID/instanceID/status?value=UP
Ref : https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations

Code : 
restTemplate.put("http://myurl/eureka/apps/myApplicationId/myInstanceId/status?value=UP", null);

Comment: The "v2" in the URL is not required in some versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I needed my service to perform some preprocessing before indicating that it was available. I did this by implementing a custom HealthIndicator that starts with a state of OUT_OF_SERVICE and transitions to UP once all of the preprocessing completed. This always seemed a hack to me but it works. Hopefully, Spencer can provide better guidance since he is an author in the Spring ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for;

```
eureka.client.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds=<some N seconds>
```

This property specifies the initial delay before the clients send health status i.e. UP etc.