Delay connect to eureka server programatically in springboot
I am using java 11 and springboot 2x. I want to connect to eureka server programatically without using properties because i want to delay registering to eureka after my cache reload and menu tree build is completed.
I am unable to find how to do so.
This is my eureka client dependency:
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
 </dependency>

This is my property file where i have set multiple properties for eureka client:
eureka.instance.statusPageUrlPath= /api/status
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath= /health
eureka.instance.hostname= localhost
eureka.client.region= default
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds= 5
eureka.client.healthcheck= true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=  http://localhost:8081/eureka/
eureka.client.enabled = true
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = true
eureka.client.fetch-registry= true
**eureka.client.register-with-eureka= false**
eureka.client.preferSameZone=true
eureka.client.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=10.50.2.17
eureka.instance.app-group-name=api
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=9090
eureka.instance.secure-port=9090
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled= false
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled= true
eureka.enabled = true

I have set
eureka.client.register-with-eureka= false
I want to connect to:

connect to eureka programatically after few of my tasks are completed.
still achieve all behaviours listed in property file.

please help...
I asked chatGPT and it gave me this code to connect:
@Autowired
 private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

 private void registerWithEureka() {
   // Register the service with Eureka programmatically
   InstanceInfo instanceInfo = eurekaClient.getApplicationInfoManager().getInfo();
   String appName = instanceInfo.getAppName();

   // Create an Application instance for registration
   Application application = new Application(appName);
   application.addInstance(instanceInfo);

   // Register the instance with Eureka
   eurekaClient.registerHealthCheck(eurekaClient.getHealthCheckHandler());
   eurekaClient.getApplications(); // Refresh Eureka registry
    }

Here my EurekaClient is coming null, even though there is @Component on my class level and @EnableEurekaClient on my SpringbootApplication class.
I am not even sure what this code does and if it is correct at all.

Hi @Apurva kumar. First of all, we strongly discourage users from using Spring Boot, 2.x, as it's been out of OSS support for over a year now and it might have security vulnerabilities. We suggest migrating to Boot 3.4.0and Cloud2024.0.0` (to be released this week). Secondly, I'd not really encourage creating your own registration/client connection unless you're an advanced user and can really evaluate the consequences of the changes.

There's a related issue on a workaround for this using statuses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123498/how-to-delay-eureka-client-registration-with-eureka-server and that's probably the best way to try.

I dont want initial status to be outOfService though. I want proper configuration of eureka client and instance and how they will connect to eureka server? If anyone knows, please help.

you will have all the configuration. you just register instances as out of service, without changing anything else, and then change them to "up" whenever your app's ready.
